# When seeking good company, need I be concerned that I'm bad company for others?

Tags: conversion, friendship

As a new Muslim, I'm encouraged to seek good company:

> One of the best ways that the Muslim can preserve and safeguard their religion is that **they be selective of who they take as friends and company**. ... **This is especially important to those Muslims who have recently embraced Islam...  They may have many habits... which are regarded as sins in Islam, and they need good company to help them in their struggle to put them aside.**  ([NewMuslims.com](http://www.newmuslims.com/lessons/28/))

[Alhamdulillah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alhamdulillah), I am fortunate enough to have met such a person.  However, I have a concern: while she is devout and educated, and thus is good company for me to keep, I'm worried that I might not be the best company for her to keep.

**Question**: When seeking good company, need I be concerned that I'm bad company for others?

The article continues...

> It is not enough, however, that you befriend just any Muslim either.  Rather, you should seek pious knowledgeable Muslims who themselves are trying their utmost to adhere to the tenets of the religion.  You may see many Muslims falling short in fulfilling the obligations and refraining from the prohibitions of the religion.

And it wouldn't be too inaccurate to say I'm the "falling short" kind of Muslim.  Maybe I'm the one who should be avoided.

Comment: I think no human is perfect, so maybe you are the "falling short" in something but your friend is falling short in others. Good company means one could learn something which changes you positively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very nice of you to think that. Masha'Allah. I find it unlikely that the person would be affected by you who is trying so hard. But yes one must be concerned. Even me as a Muslim if I commit a sin, I shouldn't reveal it to others.
I know many Muslims who go and watch the worst (full of sex) movies/ TV Series and then come and talk about to others and then are teachers of little kids as well and then tell their students to not watch such movies while the teacher themselves are talking about the last episode of the movie on their facebook page.

Having that said as generic suggestions which could be applied to anyone I'd say:

- Before meeting that person say *اعوذ بالله من الشیطان الرجیم ...بسم الله الرحمن الرحمین*. ‌(Whatever you want to do always begin it with *بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم*
- Imam Ali has actually said even if you want to read/say a poem begin
  with  *بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم*, when you want to eat food, enter your
  house, study for your exam say *بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم*. See yourself
  before Allah at ALL moments and see him as your sole protector.